# I'm trying to create a key in the registry. But when I execute this command I get an error: The specified path is invalid

Tags: c#, windows, registry

I'm trying to create a key in the registry for the Explorer Context menu. I believe I need to (or can) use:

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell via this method:

```
key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(@"\*\shell\MyApp\")
```

But when I execute this command I get an error: The specified path is invalid

I'm not sure why.

Here is a screen shot of my HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT:

[image: Screen shot of HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT]

Thanks.

Comment: Make sure you have sufficient permissions.

Comment: I think I do. I'm running VS2015 as an Admin.

Comment: I've tried key = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(@"\*\shell\");
                    key.CreateSubKey("MyApp"); but I get Cannot write to subkey error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the leading backslash.  This worked for me.

```
var key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(@"*\shell\MyApp\");
```